# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1235 This version of MySQL doesn't yet support Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, cataloginventory

I am facing below error while run **setup upgrade** commands.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1235 This version
>   of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action
>   time and event for one table', query was: CREATE TRIGGER
>   trg_cataloginventory_stock_item_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON
>   cataloginventory_stock_item FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT IGNORE INTO
>   `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES
>   (NEW.`product_id`); END

Anyone know about this issue. Please revert here.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: the most important information is missing: what version of mysql are you using?

Comment: Mysql vesion is 5.6.38 and php version is 7.1.28.

Comment: Your magento version please

Comment: Magento version is 2.2.6